# What is the fastest way to plot a 2d numpy array of pixel data with pygtk?

Tags: python, gtk, numpy, pygtk

I have a numpy array of pixel data that I want to draw at interactive speeds in pygtk.  Is there some simple, fast way to get my data onto the screen?

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with the how, but you should look up Cairo (I believe it's used by GTK+ in most platforms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything GTK specific, but have a look at [glumpy](http://code.google.com/p/glumpy/) and [pygarrayimage](http://code.astraw.com/projects/motmot/pygarrayimage.html) for fast, OpenGL based visualization (and animation) of numpy arrays.

Pygarrayimage is focused more on just getting numpy arrays as an OpenGL texture. I don't know a ton about it, but it is somewhat widely used, as far as I can tell.

Glumpy, in particular, has some [really neat demos](http://code.google.com/p/glumpy/source/browse/#hg/demos) that show its usage rather well. Unfortunately, the links to the screenshots on the homepage seem to be dead, but it's worth installing glumpy just to play around with the demos.  It's a great option for making quick interactive animations.